# Python MongoDB JSON schema validator "unresolved reference"

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am relatively new to both Python and MongoDB, I am using python to set up a MongoDB database and create a collection with schema validation. However, when I create the collection as specified in the MongoDB documentation like so:

```
db.create_collection("collection", {
        validator: {
            "$schema": "schema_stuff",
            "property1":"..."
        }
```

Pycharm throws an error saying: "Unresolved reference 'validator' "

I suspect it may have something to do with my import but I'm not sure.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because what you try to put into validator is a dictionary and `validator` is supposed to be a variable/object which is not known to Python. correct is to have `'validator'` or `"validator"` instead of `validator`.

Correct query to create collection with validator should be like this:

```
validator = {'validator': {'your validation stuff'}}    
db.create_collection("collection", validator=validator)
```

Or like this:

```
db.create_collection("collection", validator={'validator': 'your validation stuff'})
```